# A quotient of trigonometric expressions in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

How is $$\frac{\cos\frac{20\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{20\pi}{3}}{\cos{\frac{15\pi}{4}}{+i\sin\frac{15 \pi}{4}}}=\cos\frac{35\pi}{12}+i\sin\frac{35 \pi }{12}\ \ \ ?$$

I think that I am having trouble understanding a fundamental concept in complex analysis, but cannot pinpoint which.

Comment: Recall Euler's formula, $e^{iz} = \cos z + i \sin z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\cos\frac{20\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{20\pi}{3}}{\cos{\frac{15\pi}{4}}{+i\sin\frac{15 \pi}{4}}}=\frac{e^{i\frac{20\pi}{3}}}{e^{i\frac{15\pi}{4}}}$$
$$=e^{i\frac{20\pi}{3}-i\frac{15\pi}{4}}$$
$$=e^{i\frac{35}{12}}$$
$$=\cos\frac{35\pi}{12}+i\sin\frac{35 \pi }{12}$$

Answer (score 2):

You can use the complex exponential function $e^z = \cos(z) + i\sin(z)$ to rewrite you expression:

$$\frac{\cos\frac{20\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{20\pi}{3}}{\cos{\frac{15\pi}{4}}{+i\sin\frac{15 \pi}{4}}} = \frac{e^{20\pi/3}}{e^{15\pi/4}}.$$

An important point is that the complex exponential function also has the property that $e^{z_1}/e^{z_2} = e^{z_1-z_2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\cos\left(\frac{20\pi}{3}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{20\pi}{3}\right)i}{\cos\left(\frac{15\pi}{4}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{15\pi}{4}\right)i}=\frac{e^{\frac{20\pi}{3}i}}{e^{\frac{15\pi}{4}i}}=e^{\left(\frac{20\pi}{3}-\frac{15\pi}{4}\right)i}=e^{\frac{35\pi}{12}i}=\cos\left(\frac{35\pi}{12}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{35\pi}{12}\right)i$$